# Foscam Integration in Wowza using RTSP or HTTP

Tags: wowza, ip-camera

We are using Foscam F18918W model and Wowza 4.1.0

Foscam url -> http://180.151.85.194:1024/

username -> admin

password -> admin

Now this url is working fine in VLC

http://180.151.85.194:1024/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=admin&resolution=32

and we do streaming in Wowza by add a Stream File in that application.
We create myFoscam Stream in live application. And when we hit this URL using swagger UI
[http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/*defaultServer*/vhosts/*defaultVHost*/applications/live/streamfiles/myFoscam](http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles/myFoscam)

then we get this response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<StreamFile restURI="http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/streamfiles/myFoscam">
    <Version>1431524179000</Version>
    <URI>http://180.151.85.194:1024/videoStream.cgi?user=admin&amp;pwd=admin</URI>
</StreamFile>
```

And when we Test Player then this message comes **myFoscam.stream is now published.** but only black screen open, no videos

So how to get video ???

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that Foscam F18918W model sends MJPEG streaam and wowza cant stream from I.P. camera that sends MJPEG